# How do I exclude duplicate values in columns in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to find the total items for column A. But the same item is = to 1 only and just leave blank the other column if the status is Late. If status is "Arrived" then leave blank.

[SAMPLE HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVO28.png)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the header "Item" is in cell A1 with all other headers and data relative to that, delete *everything* from Col C (including the header) and place the following formula in C1:

`=ArrayFormula({"Item Total"; IF((A2:A="") + (B2:B="Arrived") + (COUNTIFS(A2:A, A2:A, ROW(A2:A), "<="&ROW(A2:A))>1),, 1)})`

A virtual array is formed between the curly brackets `{ }`.

The header "Item Total" is returned first. The semicolon means "put what follows next in the formula underneath" (i.e., under the header).

`IF` will check to see if any of three conditions is met. Those conditions are shown between three sets of parentheses joined by the `+` symbol, which here means 'OR'. Those conditions are are as follows. Either...

1.) The corresponding cell in Col A is null

2.) The corresponding cell in Col B = "Arrived"

3.) The `COUNTIFS` of the item matches from Col A up to any given row is greater than 1

If any of these conditions is true, null will be returned (as indicated by the set of commas with nothing between them).

Otherwise, 1 is returned for that row.